# CSS: Checkbox input trick not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

Consider my HTML

```
<label for="checkbox"><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"/></label>
<div class="magic_button">
    <span>Click!</span>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

and my CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
html,body {
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    height:100%;
}
#checkbox, p {
    display:none;
}
.magic_button {
    background:#27ae60;
    padding:6px 10px;
    width:20%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;
    top:calc(50% - 17px);
    left:0;
    right:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    transition:none;
    -webkit-transition:none;
    -moz-transition:none;
}
#checkbox:checked + .magic_button {
    background:#e74c3c;
    left:0;right:0;
    top:0;bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    transition:width 2s;
    -webkit-transition:width 2s;
    -moz-transition:width 2s;
}
```

I have been following tutorials and I cant for the life of me firgure out why my code isn't working. I know I can certainly use java script for this but I am trying the checkbox trick. I want to have a button vertically and horizontally centered, and when clicked, it needs the width needs to transition and it needs to expand and change colors. Does anyone know how i can get this to work? I also want the button text to disappear and then go to the paragraph text if that's possible. if not, feel free to give me some javascript if it is not pissable.

Comment: can you link the tutorial you are following?

Comment: For one thing, your closing `</label>` tag *isn't* a closing `</label>` tag ...

Comment: The checkbox should be outside the `<label>` for it to work.

Comment: Also the label needs some content or else there's nothing to click on.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kzFM/)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks, that got me on the right path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `label` element inside the `.magic_button` element. Absolutely position it to fill the entire button, allowing you to click on it and thus toggle the checkbox.

```
label {
    position:absolute;
    left:0; right:0;
    top:0; bottom:0;
}
```

That should take care of the main issue. If you want the button text to be hidden after the button is clicked, you will want to target it using the `:checked` pseudo class and set the display to `none`. Same goes for the paragraph.

Something like this will work:

```
#checkbox,
#checkbox:checked + .magic_button span,
.magic_button p {
    display:none;
}
#checkbox:checked + .magic_button p {
    display:block;
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/BFTvG/)

The reason your code wasn't working in the first place was because of the markup.

```
<label for="checkbox"><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"/></label>
<div class="magic_button">...</div>
```

The selector, `#checkbox:checked + .magic_button`, will select a `.magic_button` element that is an adjacent, succeeding sibling of the checked element. Since the checkbox is a child of the `label` element, it wasn't working. Making the `input`/`.magic_button` elements adjacent siblings allowing the element to be selected.

As an alternative to absolutely positioning the `label` element, you could have also wrapped it around the `.magic_button` element like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/4rnPa/). Of course, that means you have to change some of the selectors too.

Comment: All that needs to be done to make it work is to add some content to the `<label>` (so that there's something to click on) and move the `<input>` out of the `<label>` so that it's next to the `<div>`.

Comment: @Pointy Yea, that would work too. I was under the impression that the OP wanted to be able to click the button to toggle the checkbox. Thus, you could either wrap the element with the `label` or place the `label` within it. After all, the button said 'click'.

Comment: thanks. This works like a charm! any ideas on how I could make an 'x' at the top when the button is expanded?

Comment: @user3634438 You could use a pseudo element on the `p` element like this - http://jsfiddle.net/6ZM2W/

Comment: thanks again for all your help I gave you a checkmark